# Frequency count given a dictionary and list

Tags: python

I am attempting to perform a frequency given a dictionary with a master list containing other dictionaries.  Here is my data:

```
dict = {"costcenters": [{"facid": "A1990", "cc": "postpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1981", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory3"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1981", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory3"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "postpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "digitalpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A7881", "cc": "digitalpress", "name": "Factory2"}]
```

I want to return the Factory with the most cost centers, so in my abbreviated example here, I would want the for loop to return:

```
Factory1 - 4
```

#reason: Factory1 shows up 4 times, Factory3 shows up 2 and Factory2 once)

I don't need it broken down any further.  I have tried the following but am struggling with accessing a list with dictionaries inside and ultimately the 'name' key.

```
elements_count = {}

for cc in dict:
    if cc in elements_count:
        elements_count[cc] += 1
    else:
        elements_count[cc] = 1

print(max(elements_count))
```

Nothing prints when I run this, so I don't have any error messages to share.  The simplest solution would be best so that I can understand how to capture frequencies in the future.  Thank you! :)

Comment: your code contains some bugs. E.g. you shouldn't use name `dict`, because then you can't create dictionaries using `dict()`. Then by `{}` you don't create a dictionary, but a set. Then I guess, you want to iterate over the elements of the "costcenters" key. You can do this with `for cc_dict in dict['costcenters']:`followed by `cc_dict['name']' to get the name of the factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run this I get `costcenters`.

I think you want to do:

```
import sys

data = {"costcenters": [{"facid": "A1990", "cc": "postpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1981", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory3"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1981", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory3"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "postpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "digitalpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A7881", "cc": "digitalpress", "name": "Factory2"}]}


elements_count = {}

for cc in data["costcenters"]:
    factory = cc["name"]
    if factory in elements_count:
        elements_count[factory] += 1
    else:
        elements_count[factory] = 1

max_value=0
min_value=sys.maxsize*sys.maxsize
for item in elements_count:
    if elements_count[item] > max_value:
        max_value = elements_count[item]
        factory_max = item
    elif elements_count[item] < min_value:
        min_value = elements_count[item]
        factory_min = item

 
print(f'Maximum Value: {factory_max} - {max_value}')
print(f'Minimum Value: {factory_min} - {min_value}')
```

Output:

`Maximum Value: Factory1 - 4`

`Minimum Value: Factory2 - 1`

This assumes your number of factories is no bigger than `sys.maxsize` squared (you're talking many billions here), but obviously this could be changed for the largest realistic number.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance.  I like the idea of f strings and would like to learn more about these.  This worked!

Comment: Additional question: so if you wanted to find min(), would you reverse the sign in your if elements_count[item] > max_value line?

Comment: @tlazas912 - I have updated for you to show the minimum as well. If you found my answer helpful you can upvote it and click the tick to show it was the "accepted answer". If you want to read more on f-strings, there's lots of good information [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python).

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple solution for this problem could be:

```
my_dict = {"costcenters": [{"facid": "A1990", "cc": "postpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1981", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory3"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1981", "cc": "prepress", "name": "Factory3"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "postpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A1990", "cc": "digitalpress", "name": "Factory1"},
                       {"facid": "A7881", "cc": "digitalpress", "name": "Factory2"}]}

counter_dict = {}
for key in my_dict["costcenters"]:
    counter_dict[key["name"]] = counter_dict.get(key["name"], 0) + 1
    
max_factory = max(counter_dict, key = counter_dict.get)
print(f"{max_factory}:", counter_dict[f"{max_factory}"])
```

The output will be:

```
Factory1: 4
```

Comment: Great Lorenzo..this worked as well, and again, I noticed your use of f strings to print out the results.  Thank you!

Comment: @tlazas912 Perfect! I see above that you asked about finding the min factory, here you can simply add a line `min_factory = min(counter_dict, key = counter_dict.get)` to find which factory is the one with less centers